# How to know the type of object a pointer points to in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have defined two classes based on one basic class：

```
class Basic
{
public:
   int i;
};
class DerivedA:public Basic
{
 public:
   int j;
};
class DerivedB:public Basic
{
 public:
   int k;
};
```

Then now have a class named Collect, which contains the pointer to the `Basic` class

```
class Collect
{
 public:
    Basic *pBasic;
    void run();

};
```

In this class, a function `run()` has been defined, which will perform some operations based on the type of the object the pointer points to:

```
void Collect::run()
{
  if (pBasic points to DerivedA object)
  {

   }

  if (pBasic points to DerivedB object)
  {

   }

};
```

Then my question is as follows:

- With C++, is it possible to know the type of object the pointer points to?
- Is it a good practice to perform something different based on the type of object the pointer points to as illustrated in `run` function?

Comment: Yes, at least it is possible to check whether it points to an object of a specific type. No. Typically you use polymorphism for that.

Comment: We usually say "Base", not "Basic".

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's already polymorphism. You mean virtual dispatch.

Comment: Use `typeid` if you want, but the compiler does it for you anyway.

Comment: check out `dynamic_cast`, and I agree with @juansanchopanza. Casts are a hacky way of programming, use normal C++ polymorphism.

Comment: @juanchopanza The LLVM and Clang developer teams might disagree with you on that point. A lot.

Comment: @ghs.st I'm curious, do you have any reference for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a check like this your base class `Basic` needs to have at least one virtual member. Since you wish to build a class hierarchy, I would tend to make `~Basic` virtual to ensure it will be [properly deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) at the same time.

The reasoning behind this is that the by including a `virtual` member, you force each object of the class to contain a pointer to the class specific [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which the implementation can then use to perform your check.

```
class Basic
{
public:
    int i;
    virtual ~Basic() { }
};
class DerivedA:public Basic
{
public:
    int j;
};
class DerivedB:public Basic
{
public:
    int k;
};
```

Now you can write your check:

```
void Collect::run()
{
    if (DerivedA* pDerived = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(pBasic)) { }
    if (DerivedB* pDerived = dynamic_cast<DerivedB*>(pBasic)) { }
};
```

The `dynamic_cast` will return a `nullptr` if it fails, so you will only enter the body of the `if` when your cast succeeded and `pDerived` contains a valid pointer to the right derived object.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ we usually use **Base** class, not Basic class.

Anyway, in general, if your base class is polymorphic (that contains virtual functions) you can use dynamic_cast:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    void test() { cout << "Base" ; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
   void test() { cout << "Derived" ; }
}; 

void main() {
   Base* a = new Derived();
   if(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(a)) {
      a->test(); /* print "Derived" */
   }
}
```

This means that object "a" has "static-type": Base; and "dynamic-type": Derived.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your base class have virtual functions, the pointee of your pointer will always be of type `Basic`, and have the behavior of an object of type `Basic`. Actually, even with virtual function, a pointer of type `Basic*` always points to an object of type `Basic`. But the ''dynamic type'' of the pointee can be different.

If your base class have at least one virtual function, then your can rely on the [Run-time type information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_informationRTTI/.): you can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) or [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to get the dynamic type of the pointee.